# How to "listen to" directory size changes?

Tags: files, directory, size, inotify

I need to do some actions when a directory grows above a certain size limit.

Obviously, obtaining the size can be done with `du`, but a single run of `du` takes a long time in my case, loads the disk quite a lot, and does not give "instantaneous" feedback.

It would be possible to set up inotify for each file and directory in a tree, sum up the result, and maintain the sum in the memory, but it would be a lot of work if done by hand.

Is there a way to "listen to size changes" efficiently?

Comment: You would probably want to use fanotify instead of inotify, it’s much more efficient and takes care of handling the queue of events for you.

Answer (score 3):

This approach might not be available to you, but when it comes to assessing the total size of a large number of files, `df` is far more efficient than `du` (because it uses the filesystem's built-in size totals rather than re-measuring every individual file's size).

To achieve this, you would create a separate filesystem for the files under this directory, and mount the filesystem somewhere like `/data/somedir` (and set a symbolic link to the mount point from this directory's usual place).  And move the files there, of course.  Now `df` is available as a lightweight and fast way to see changes for this collection of files.